# undefined index php

Tags: php, formularios, variables, sesiones

Tengo este codigo, el caso es que en la linea del $_SESSION['alumnos'] me salta el error. Lo que quiero es que si ese array de alumnos no existe que lo cree, y al comenzar el programa, como no existe me da ese error, en cuanto se crea no avisa de nada. ¿Como lo podria evitar?

> Notice: Undefined index: alumnos in
>   C:\wamp\www\arraySesiones\index.php on line 5

```
<?php
session_start();
require('recursos/funciones.php');

if (!$_SESSION['alumnos']) {
  $_SESSION['alumnos'] = [];
}

if (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
  registrarAlumno();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Array Sesiones</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" value="">
      <label for="apellido">Apellido: </label>
      <input type="text" name="apellido" value="">

      <input type="submit" name="registrar" value="Registrar">
      </form>

      <form  action="mostrarResultados.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="cerrar" value="Cerrar">
      </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿con isset igual que haces para registrarAlumno?

Comment: @PedroPrada registrarAlumno es una funcion que tengo en un archivo externo, el error me da el la linea 5, en el `if (!$_SESSION['alumnos']) {
  $_SESSION['alumnos'] = [];
}`

Comment: Lo que me refiero es que uses isset: if (!isset($_SESSION['alumnos'])) {
  $_SESSION['alumnos'] = [];
}

Comment: @PedroPrada en la funcion registrarAlumno lo uso: `function registrarAlumno(){

if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido'])) {
  $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
  $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];

  array_push($_SESSION['alumnos'],[$nombre=>$apellido]);
}else{
  echo "Ingresa nombre y apellido";
}

}`

Comment: Me temo que no nos estamos entendiendo.

Answer (score 3):

Como bien te indican en algun comentario puedes utilizar `isset()` para determinar si la variable existe y no es `null` o `false`

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('recursos/funciones.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['alumnos'])) {
  $_SESSION['alumnos'] = [];
}

if (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
  registrarAlumno();
}
```

Documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php